# facing error with awk command

Tags: awk

input:

```
123456.00|aswani|india|ap
23456.00|rani|us|tel
233|ramu|londan|vih
```

output:

```
aswani|ap
rani|tel
ramu|vih
```

I'm trying for this output with the command

```
awk '{FS="|";OFS="|"}{print $2,$4}'
```

but I'm getting output as:

```
|
rani|tel
ramu|vih
```

command was executing from 2 line but not from first line. i'm trying for output along with first line

Answer (score 2):

You should put the first block (setting FS and OFS) inside a "BEGIN" block:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";OFS="|"} {print $2,$4}'
```

A "BEGIN" block will run *before* the first line of text is processed. In contrast, the stand-alone block you had will run on *every* line of text, but for the first line, setting FS will happen too late, since the fields will have been split already.

An alternative is to set FS through an awk command line option, but you still need to take care of OFS:

```
awk -F '|' '{OFS="|"; print $2,$4}'
```

Or:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{print $2,$4}'
```

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by @Kusalananda, some `awk` implementations (such as BSD awk) will re-split the fields if FS gets reset, so that setting doesn't need to happen in a "BEGIN" block. In GNU awk (which is typically the one found in Linux distributions), that does not happen, so FS needs to be set before the line is split.

Comment: Can you add explanation?

Comment: @PRY Added an explanation.

Comment: @Kusalananda I believe the problem is that it's setting FS too late, after the fields have been split on the first line. See my edited answer.

Comment: @filbranden You are correct. It's a GNU `awk` thing. I was testing with BSD `awk` and it's re-splitting as soon as you change `FS`.  Good catch!

Comment: See also the `FS = OFS = "|"` syntax or `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|'`

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks! Updated the answer to include the bit on how that works in BSD awk but not in GNU awk. In any case, it seems doing that in a BEGIN block is safest...

Answer (score 2):

As [filbranden points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504961/116858) GNU `awk` (and `mawk`) requires `FS` to be correctly set *before* reading the first line, otherwise it will split the line on the default field separator (a sequence of whitespaces).  Your code sets `FS` *after* reading each line, so it will have the wrong value while processing the first line of the file.

OpenBSD `awk` (at least) behaves differently and appears to split the current record when a field is accessed, but not before that. This means that your code actually works on an OpenBSD system.

I'm just going to add to that and say that to extract a set of columns from a file with no further processing, the `cut` command is also useful:

```
$ cut -d '|' -f 2,4 <file
aswani|ap
rani|tel
ramu|vih
```

Comment: The splitting is done using the value of `FS` at the time the record is read, it's no about doing it before the first line. `printf 'a,b\nc,d\n' | awk '{FS=","; print $1}'` prints `a,b` and `c`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That prints `a` and `c` on OpenBSD.

Comment: Then OpenBSD `awk` is not POSIX compliant in that regard. Solaris's `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and busybox `awk` behave like GNU `awk`.

Comment: In BSDs, the splitting is done using the value of IFS at the time the first reference to a field or `NF` is made.

Comment: Note that the `cut` and `awk` behaviour differ on lines with fewer than 4 fields (also note the non-intuitive behaviour of `cut` when the input has only one field (no separator))